# pulling mysql data for timelinejs?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to pull data from a mysql database to create a json file for use with a timelinejs timeline.  The problem is that the json file must be formatted a certain way. I've created the following code that formats the json correctly, but it is only pulling one entry from my database (specifically the last entry).  Any help you guys could offer would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "********") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("php_test") or die("Could not select database");
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timelinetest");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    $object = array
    ('timeline'=>
        array(
        'headline'=>'Georgia History Title Page', 
        'type'=>'default', 
        'text'=> 'Testing Overview', 
        'startDate'=>'1700', 
        'asset'=>array('media'=>'titlepagemedia', 'credit'=>'titlepagecredit', 'caption'=>'titlepagecaption'), 
        'date'=>array(array('startDate'=>($row['startDate']), 'endDate'=>($row['endDate']), 'headline'=>($row[        'headline']), 'text'=>($row['text']), 'tag'=>'', 'asset'=>array('media'=>($row['media']), 'credit'=>($row[        'credit']), 'caption'=>($row['caption']))), ), 
        'era'=>array(array('startDate'=>'', 'endDate'=>'', 'headline'=>'', 'text'=>'', 'tag'=>'')) 
        )
    );

$json = json_encode($object);
file_put_contents("testing.json", $json);
?>



<head>
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- BEGIN TimelineJS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline/latest/js/storyjs-embed.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                createStoryJS({
                    type:       'timeline',
                    width:      '800',
                    height:     '600',
                    source: 'http://localhost/php_test/timeline_test/testing.json',
                    embed_id:   'my-timeline'
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!-- END TimelineJS -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop you keep assigning (=overwriting) the contents of your result vector `$row` to the same (singular!) object `$object`. Not being familiar with TimelineJS I assume that you need to build up an array in `$object['timeline']` which you could do with

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $object['timeline'][]=array(
        'headline'=>'Georgia History Title Page', 
        'type'=>'default', 
        'text'=> 'Testing Overview', 
        'startDate'=>'1700', 
        'asset'=>array('media'=>'titlepagemedia', 'credit'=>'titlepagecredit', 'caption'=>'titlepagecaption'), 
        'date'=>array(array(
            'startDate'=>($row['startDate']),
            'endDate'=>($row['endDate']), 
            'headline'=>($row['headline']),
            'text'=>($row['text']),
            'tag'=>'',
            'asset'=>array('media'=>($row['media']),
            'credit'=>($row['credit']),
            'caption'=>($row['caption'])))), 
        'era'=>array(array('startDate'=>'', 'endDate'=>'', 'headline'=>'', 'text'=>'', 'tag'=>'')) 
        );
}
```

This is essentially the same as `array_push($object['timeline'], ...)` and it will append the data from each of your result rows to the array `'timeline'` in `$object`.

**Edit**

Now the loop will fill the arrays `date` and `era` within `$object['timeline']` (although there will be no real data in `era`):

```
$object=array('timeline'=>array(
    'headline'=>'Georgia History Title Page', 
    'type'=>'default', 
    'text'=> 'Testing Overview', 
    'startDate'=>'1700', 
    'asset'=>array('media'=>'titlepagemedia', 'credit'=>'titlepagecredit', 'caption'=>'titlepagecaption'), 
    'date'=>array(),'era'=>array()
));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $object['timeline']['date'][]=array(
            'startDate'=>($row['startDate']),
            'endDate'=>($row['endDate']), 
            'headline'=>($row['headline']),
            'text'=>($row['text']),
            'tag'=>'',
            'asset'=>array('media'=>($row['media']),
            'credit'=>($row['credit']),
            'caption'=>($row['caption']))); 
    $object['timeline']['era'][]=array('startDate'=>'', 'endDate'=>'', 'headline'=>'', 'text'=>'', 'tag'=>'');

}
```

Maybe this helps?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! The problem with this solution is that it repeats the title page (the first array) and this prevents the timeline from loading.  I need the title array to be static, and then the date, asset, and era arrays to loop. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I am still learning about your TimeLine object. It sems that the `date`-array could be the structure that needs to be filled within your loop. There is an `asset` within in, bzt `era` is definitely on the same level as your title and can not be looped. I 'll edit my post ...

Comment: This worked! I really appreciate it. I've been stuck on this for days. I'm relatively new at this kind of code and I didn't realize the array could be split up like that. So, one last question. Later on, I'll want to be able to display only certain dates from the database. Would I use `where` and `between` for that?

Comment: Yes, definitely, for example: `SELECT * FROM timelinetest WHERE startDate BETWEEN '2010-1-1' AND '2012-6-30'` would get you everything with a start date between 1. January 2010 and 30. June 2012.